# Adding balance into client account using paypal

Tags: php, paypal

This is my first experience to work at any eCommerce site. I am looking for a simple and secure way to add virtual balance into client account deposited from Paypal.

For example, clients will have a "ADD Funds" button on their dashboard at our website. They will click and fill a simple input field to put an amount they want to add.

If client enter 100.00 USD, page should redirect to Paypal and after successful transaction, client should see balance at their dashboard at our website.

Any help will be appreciable? Looking forward to hear from you guys.

Comment: From where they will pay, another paypal acount or credit card?

Comment: They will pay from their Paypal account and that balance will be added  into their account at our website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal offers a number of products to make it as simple or complicated as you'd like.

If all you want is to receive a specific amount, with no checks, no backend processing, it can be as simple as populating a specific  with GET or POST variables and sending it off to PayPal. PayPal Payments Standard would be a suitable product in this case.

If however you'd like just a little more functionality; i.e. receive data back about the transaction which just occurred, you can look at Payments Standard and supplement it with Instant Payment Notification.

IPN is essentially what is nowadays known as 'webhooks'. Whenever a transactional event occurs on your account, you're notified at a specific URL with a HTTP POSt with data about this event.

If the second option is what you'd like to go with, here's an example to get you started:

GET:
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=yourPayPalaccount@domain.tld&amount=1&currency_code=EUR&notify_url=http://yourhost.tld/ipnscript.php

POST:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="yourPayPalaccount@domain.tld">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://yourhost.tld/ipnscript.php">
<input type="submit" value="Pay with PayPal">
</form>
```

For a list of all available variables you can use with Payments Standard, I'd suggest taking a look at [this link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/).

If you look through the variables I included above, you'll see I also specified `notify_url`.
`notify_url` is how you specify a per-transaction IPN listener URL.
Whilst you can also set it up in your PayPal profile, most of our users tend to supply it along with each transaction (that way the URL can vary between transactions as well).

To get started with IPN, I would recommend [this guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/).
If you'd like to dive right in, we have IPN sample code [in our GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/).

Want to test it out? Head over to https://developer.paypal.com/, login with your live PayPal account and under 'Applications' > 'Sandbox accounts' you can create a couple tests accounts to get started with.
If you're testing in sandbox, remember that your GET/POST should point to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ and not https://www.paypal.com/ (which is the live PayPal site).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you could handle that, but I'd recommend going with [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/).

PayPal's system will send POST data to a listener script that you have on your server any time a transaction hits your PayPal account, and it happens in real-time.

This allows you to automate procedures like updating your database, sending out customized email notifications, hitting 3rd party web services, etc. and again, it happens in real-time so the automated actions would happen instantly.

If you're working with PHP you can get going very quickly and easily with my [IPN template for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-instant-payment-notification-ipn-php-template/).

Comment: Caveat: IPN itself is not a checkout product. It supplements checkout products such as Payments Standard, Express Checkout or Payments Pro by sending a server-to-server HTTP POST with transactional data to a URL you specify.